# Remove Object from Array MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to remove a specific object from my mongoDB array.

Should remove the info above inside the red cube but (0: Object)

[image: MongoDB Schema]

I tried the way I show below but didn't work.
And I need to remove the entire object but can't pass the values directly in the query so I need to grab the info from mongoDB and remove them.

```
router.post("/deleteArquive/:id", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
  House.update(
    { "expensesHouse._id": id },
    {
      $pull: {
        expensesHouse: {
          status: "expensesHouse.status",
          _id: "expensesHouse._id",
          expenseType: "expensesHouse.expenseType"
        }
      }
    }
  ).then(house => {
    if (house.userID !== req.user.id) {
      res.redirect("/houses/houses");
    } else {
      req.flash("success_msg", "House removed!");
      res.redirect("/houses/houses");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Where do you get `"expensesHouse.status"` and the other two values from ?

Comment: The way I show above is what I tried but I don't know how I can get the specific values I pass into.

Comment: @CarlosOrelhas What do you need those values for? You have the id, don't you?

Comment: @Mafor I have the specific ID and what I need is remove the expense from my house but only the right one (id should match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the requirements correctly, this should do the job:

```
House.update(
  { "expensesHouse._id": id },
  { 
    $pull: {
      expensesHouse: {
        _id: id
      }
    } 
  }
)
```

Comment: It works!! I just think I need to $pull every field so it gets me lost! :)